# Objective - C : unsigned int to base64

Tags: objective-c, base64

My server devs ask me to send them some data encoded with base64 with this rules:

1. big-endian byte order
2. no extra zero bytes
3. base64 string

```
for example:
10005000 → «mKol»
1234567890 → «SZYC0g»
```

I did some spaghetti code, and it's work. But maybe somebody have more elegant solution?

```
+ (NSString*)encodeBigEndianBase64:(uint32_t)value {

    char *bytes = (char*) &value;
    int len = sizeof(uint32_t);

    char *reverseBytes = malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    unsigned long index = len - 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        reverseBytes[index--] = bytes[i];

    int offset = 0;

    while (reverseBytes[offset] == 0) {
        offset++;
    }

    NSData *resultData;

    if (offset > 0) {

        int truncatedLen = (len - offset);
        char *truncateBytes = malloc(sizeof(char) * truncatedLen);

        for (int i = 0; i < truncatedLen ; i++)
            truncateBytes[i] = reverseBytes[i + offset];

        resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:truncateBytes length:truncatedLen];
        free(truncateBytes);

    } else {

        resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:reverseBytes length:len];
    }

    free(reverseBytes);

    return [[resultData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@""];

}
```

Little bit improved solution (thanks to zaph):

```
+ (NSString*)encodeBigEndianBase64:(uint32_t)value {

uint32_t swappedValue = CFSwapInt32HostToBig(value);

char *swappedBytes = (char*) &swappedValue;
int len = sizeof(uint32_t);

int offset = 0;

while (swappedBytes[offset] == 0) {
    offset++;
}

NSData *resultData;

if (offset > 0) {

    int truncatedLen = (len - offset);
    char *truncateBytes = malloc(sizeof(char) * truncatedLen);

    for (int i = 0; i < truncatedLen ; i++)
        truncateBytes[i] = swappedBytes[i + offset];

    resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:truncateBytes length:truncatedLen];
    free(truncateBytes);

} else {

    resultData = [NSData dataWithBytes:swappedBytes length:len];
}

return [[resultData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@""];
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For endian conversions use `htons()`, `htonl()`, `ntohs()`, `ntohl()`

network byte order is bigendian

```
`htons()` // host to network short
`htonl()` // host to network ling
`ntohs()` // network to host long
`ntohl()` // network to host long
```

These are defined in endan.h

Also see [Byte-Order Utilities Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation//CoreFoundation/Reference/CFByteOrderUtils/index.html)